# UINPUT device program in C for Ubuntu 14.04 does not work. Why?

Tags: c, ubuntu-14.04, keypress, elevated-privileges, uinput

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and I am setting up a virtual keyboard in c, which requires uinput to work.

I had this root privilege problem:

```
ls -l /dev/uinput 
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 10, 223 Feb 25 11:11 /dev/uinput
```

But I solved it by creating a new rule for this. It now prints:

```
ls -l /dev/uinput
crw-rw---- 1 root uinput 10, 223 Feb  26 21:11 /dev/uinput
```

This however still doesn't solve my problem and my program still doesn't work, even with sudo.

Here's my code:

```
int main()
{
int uinp_fd;
int i;

uinp_fd = open("/dev/uinput", O_WRONLY|O_NDELAY);

if(uinp_fd < 0)
{

    printf("Unable to open /dev/uinput\n");
    return -1;
}

else printf("Can open /dev/uinput\n");

/********* Setup input device structure section: ***********/

memset(&uinp,0,sizeof(uinp));

snprintf(uinp.name, UINPUT_MAX_NAME_SIZE, "The C Keyboard");
uinp.id.bustype = BUS_USB;  
uinp.id.version = 1;
uinp.id.vendor = 0x1234;
uinp.id.product = 0xfedc;

write(uinp_fd, &uinp, sizeof(uinp));


/****** Setup the uinput keyboard device section: **********/

ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY);
ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_SYN);
ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_REP);

ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_SET_KEYBIT, KEY_A);

ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_DEV_CREATE, NULL);

if (ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_DEV_CREATE, NULL) < 0)
{
    printf("Unable to create UINPUT device.\n");
    return -1;
}
```

My source code continues on further from there.

However, the program always prints "Unable to create UINPUT device.".

sudo command to run my program also doesn't work and the same error message is printed. 
What should I do to get the program to work? Thanks.

Comment: Please show a [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That line by itself is not enough info. You may be doing something wrong or missing before that (there is some config that needs to be done before the UI_DEV_CREATE). And as a first debugging step print out `errno` or call `perror` to get a more precise error reason.

Comment: I have included a chunk of my source code for verification.
Hope that it is enough. I greatly appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what it was before, but please do as @kaylum said. This ignores many system call return values, and is not even compilable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_DEV_CREATE, NULL);

if (ioctl(uinp_fd, UI_DEV_CREATE, NULL) < 0)
{
    printf("Unable to create UINPUT device.\n");
    return -1;
}
```

You have invoked the UI_DEV_CREATE ioctl twice. The first call will succeed and the second will fail. So just delete the first call.

Comment: Thanks. That does work. But my program still doesn't print anything. I am trying to print the letter a on terminal. But as of now; as per your reply, it just opens and creates a device, and then doesn't do anything else. I will upload the rest of my source code. Hope you can help. Thanks!

Comment: @jara Please ask that in a new question.

Comment: I have created a new question for this topic. My entire source code is there: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35666314/uinput-device-program-in-c-for-ubuntu-14-04-does-not-work-why-part-2

Hope you can help. Thanks!